# Google sheets - getting percentages of yes, no, maybe responses into a pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have some data.  One of the columns (Column D) has data such as "yes", "no", 'Credit", "n/a", "half".

At the top of that column, I have created a function which allows me to get percentage of "yes" responses, but not as a percentage of all responses, but just as a percentage of the responses that are "Yes", "No" and "Half"
Formula below

=iferror((COUNTIF(C3:C, "yes") / (COUNTIF(C3:C, "no") + COUNTIF(C3:C, "half") + COUNTIF(C3:C, "yes"))))

Below that, starting at row 3, is the data.

What I want to do is put data this into a pivot table.  One of my other Columns is date, and I want to be able to group the data by month (actually by week, but I have already worked that out).

I am looking for my grand total value to be summarised using the formula above, which doesn't exist as one of the standard summary options.

I am interested to hear your ideas on the best way to solve this.

Thanks

Edit:  here is a link to a sheet with the basics of what I am trying to do.  Thanks for your help with this.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ew4pPv4qtJCZJCaUgg_I7VdL5F00t-PFhIlg2bs8sh0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: To give a simpler example.  Let's just say I have "yes", "no", and "maybe" responses in the column.
I am looking to get the percentage of "yes" vs "no" into the pivot table summaries, without counting "maybe" responses.  

Thanks

Comment: Share a copy of your spreadsheet and we can answer correctly using the pivot table, without adding a column.

Comment: @MikeSteelson

here is a link to a sheet with the basics of what I am trying to do.  Thanks for your help with this.  

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ew4pPv4qtJCZJCaUgg_I7VdL5F00t-PFhIlg2bs8sh0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

One "extended" solution is

get all yes per month in L3

```
=query({arrayformula(EOMONTH(B$3:B,0)),C3:C},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2='yes' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Exercice-yes' ")
```

get all yen/no/half per month in N3

```
=query({arrayformula(EOMONTH(B$3:B,0)),C3:C},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2='yes' or Col2='no' or Col2='half' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Exercice-yes|no|half' ")
```

get all unique monthes in G3

```
=arrayformula(unique(if(B3:B="","",eomonth(B3:B,0))))
```

and finally find the %

```
=arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(G3:G,L:M,2,0)/VLOOKUP(G3:G,N:O,2,0)))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your responses.  I'm looking at this now, but not sure I can get my head around it all right now.